# Name for this notion of "pair-wise reduced" basis?

Tags: reference-request, integer-lattices

Let $\mathcal{B}=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ be a basis for a full-rank lattice $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.  Say the basis is "pair-wise reduced" if for all $i\neq j$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{\langle b_i,b_j\rangle}{\langle b_j,b_j\rangle}<\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Is there a name for this sort of "pair-wise reduced" basis?  Does it imply any nice properties, e.g. bounds on the shortest vector in $\Lambda$ in terms of $\mathcal{B}$?  Any references or reasons why this isn't interesting are appreciated.